# PHP, XAMPP (index):6792 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: php, google-bigquery, xampp

When I try to get access to http://localhost/test.php, I got the error `(index):6792 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.` At a browser. I could see it by typing `F12`.
I confirmed that `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` is the reason but cannot find how to fix it.
I alredy checked all related issues but they did not help me.
The final goal is to manipulate BigQuery from php file.

### Environment

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- XAMPP

### How to set up

```bash
# Install php
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y php

# Install Composer
$ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
$ php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
$ php composer-setup.php
$ php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

# Enable Composer
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install bigquery package
$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/
$ sudo composer require google/cloud-bigquery
# composer.json, composer.lock and vendor/ are created.
```

### Folder structure

php files and requirements are located in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`.

```bash
my-pc@my-pc:/opt/lampp/htdocs/$ tree -L 1

├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── test.php
└── vendor/
```

- test.php

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
    // omission
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

### Reference

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php

Comment: Can you try to include `$ rm -r /vendor` in the set of scripts or delete the `/vendo` directory before executing `$ composer require google/cloud-bigquery`.Let me know if this solved your issue or not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. By running `sudo composer require google/cloud-bigquery`, `vendor` directory will be created.